# Please see my routine

Tags: exercise

I work most of my time typing or writing. I got myself a bench, a squat rack, a barbell, a dumbbell. I told the shopkeeper that I don't get time to exercise 1-2 hours at a stretch and so he has provided me a exercise plan and a diet plan. Please consider reviewing this routine. This is not like the routine that the neighborhood boys do at gym, so I am worried.

| Day | 5:30 - 6:15 AM | 5 - 5:45 PM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1st | Walk and bench | Walk and biceps |
| 2nd | Walk and row | Walk and triceps |
| 3rd | Walk and press | Walk and forearms |
| 4th | Walk and squat | Walk and grip |

The evening walk is me coming back from work. I try to maintain pace though. The shopkeeper has asked me to do 100 times each exercise and weight as:

| Exercise | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| Bench | 20 KG |
| Row | 5 KG dumbbell |
| Squat | 20 KG |
| Press | 5 KG dumbbell |
| Evening | 6 KG barbell |

Also, I have been asked to do it everyday cycling the routines, even on Sundays.

Comment: That's the whole routine?

Comment: Yes JohnP. I get very short free time. So, morning and evening, I was asked to walk and do only one exercise each time.

Comment: What does "100 times each exercise" mean? Do you mean 1 set of 100 reps for each exercise? Also, what does "everyday cycling the routines, even on Sundays" mean?

Comment: David, yes. 100 times mean 100 reps, but not in 1 set. I am asked to lift it with less rest and finish 100 reps. I can do, lets say, 30, 27, 17, 14,.. till I reach 100. by cycling, I mean I do one routine after the other. Mon-1 Tue-2 Wed-3 Th-4 Fr-1 Sat-2 Sun-3 Mon-4 Tu-1, like this. I have to exercise everyday. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: @Gary2 are the dumbbell and barbell fixed weight, or adjustable? Adjustable means you have weight plates you can add to the barbell and dumbbell to make them heavier, and fixed weight means the weight of them not change.

Comment: What are your goals? What's your training experience? As David asked, are the weights adjustable or fixed?

Comment: @David, yes. My barbell and dumbbells are both adjustable. I have two 10 kg, two 5 kg, two 3 kg, and two 2 kg plates.

Comment: @Dark Hippo, my goal is to lose some fat. I have little experience. I have learned the exercises few years ago but didn't exercise since then. My weights are adjustable.

Comment: A workout can be done in 45mins to an hour! No need for 100 reps in my opinion. 100 reps is like the German volume training. Your muscles need adequate rest to recover and grow too. May consider a push, pull, legs split. 3 workouts per week.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a better routine.

Work harder than yesterday.
The one you have one is basically just a tutorial, probably given to you to teach you the basic movements.

It is smarter to push yourself more every time you train... You train to do get better not to do the same thing over and over again.

Pick your own goals and work it up.

Want big arms? Weighted pull ups, do more everytime

Want big legs? Squats, do more everytime..

You can start off with 3 sets as warm up with light weight and 5 heavy sets... Weight doesn't matter as long as you feel it is actually hard and pushing your limits, it must feel heavy for you.

Don't waste time doing too many exercises,  maybe do some calf raises or maybe face-pulls...
But keep it at 3 exercises max....

Only advanced athletes who do it for a job need many exercises, unless you want to be competing for money, you need only 2 or 3 exercises.

How many repetitions? As many as you can.

How much weight? As much as you can without hurting yourself.

Answer (score 1):

After receiving all the valuable suggestions, advises here, I talked to a gym owner and he gave me a routine which takes 30 minutes for me complete. I have started it already. I am sharing here for all busy individuals like me.

Special Thanks to David, Dark Hippo and Jun.

```
|  Day     |   Exercises   | Sets | Reps | Rest between sets| Rest after ex |
|----------|---------------|------|------|------------------|---------------|
| Sunday   | Shoulder Press| 3    |  8   |     30 s         | 1 minute      |
|          | Shrugs        | 3    | 15   |     30 s         |    -          |
|----------|---------------|------|------|------------------|---------------|
| Monday   |                  Rest                                          |
|----------|---------------|------|------|------------------|---------------|
| Tuesday  | Squat         | 3    |  5   |     50 s         | 2 minutes     |
|          | Bench Press   | 3    |  5   |     30 s         | 1 minute      |
|          | Dumbbell row  | 3    |  8   |     30 s         |    -          |
|----------|---------------|------|------|------------------|---------------|
| Wednesday| Curl          | 3    | 20   |     30 s         | 1 minute      |
|          | Skull crushers| 3    | 20   |     30 s         | 1 minute      |
|          | Forearm curl  | 3    | 20   |     30 s         |    -          |
|----------|---------------|------|------|------------------|---------------|
| Thursday |                  Rest                                          |
|----------|---------------|------|------|------------------|---------------|
| Friday   | Squat         | 3    |  5   |     50 s         | 2 minutes     |
|          | Bench Press   | 3    |  5   |     30 s         | 1 minute      |
|          | Dumbbell row  | 3    |  8   |     30 s         |    -          |
|----------|---------------|------|------|------------------|---------------|
| Saturday | Curl          | 3    | 20   |     30 s         | 1 minute      |
|          | Skull crushers| 3    | 20   |     30 s         | 1 minute      |
|          | Forearm curl  | 3    | 20   |     30 s         |    -          |
|----------|---------------|------|------|------------------|---------------|
```

Other than these, I am asked to walk to work and back to home. I need to increase the weight by 2 KG every two weeks for three months, after that increase weight by 2 KG every week.

Comment: Toss some deadlifts in there if you have more than 30 minutes.

Comment: Just seeing your original post and this follow-up answer. The original plan has a lot of walking. If you spend all day sitting at a desk, the cardio from walking would be really great for you. Your routine is good too, but that cardio will keep you healthy and feeling great.

Comment: @jp2code Thank you for your encouraging words. I am feeling great these days, I feel lighter.

Comment: @C.Lange I really like deadlifts. As per the words of the gym owner who gave the routine I can do deadlift after 6 months. My routine is like this: 1. Above routine for 3 months, increasing weight every 2 weeks. 2. Above routine for 3 months, increasing weight every week. 3. After these 6 months, there is a different routine, which I will take it after 6 months in the beginning of May. He told me it has deadlift, pullups, lunges, etc.